# Why create and use Bundle in IOS?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I'd like to know which is the exact purpose of a bundle. 
In other terms, when is a good practice to use them and when it would be discouraged ?

I found [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/LoadingCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000052-SW1) relative to OSX, is it a good point to start ?

Comment: what do you want to do? without knowing the problem nobody can tell you if bundles are the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bundle is way of packaging applications for Mac OS X. Therefore iOS inherited this feature also. So when an application is deployed to the system, the binary and resources are in this bundle.  On iOS, you can only read your own bundle.  But on a Mac OS X, you can read other bundles on the system.